# Unity Jumping Issue - Character won't jump if it walks to the platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

(This is a 2D project)

I have a jumping issue where if my character WALKS into an X platform, she won't jump, but when she JUMPS ONTO the X platform, she can perform a jump.

**For the platforms** I am currently using 2 Box Collider 2Ds (one with "is trigger" checked)

**For the character** I am currently using 2 Box Collider 2Ds (one with "is trigger" checked) and Rigidbody 2D.

Below is the code for jumping and grounded I am currently trying to use.

```c#
{
    public float Speed;
    public float Jump;
    bool grounded = false;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (grounded)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, Jump);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
        grounded = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D()
    {
        grounded = false;
    }
}
```

Issue arises on the same part of every platform. (Each square represents a single platform sprite and they have all the same exact characteristics, since I copy pasted each one of them). Please check the photo on this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/52TJ5.jpg

Comment: I suggest you to uncheck the "istrigger" on bouth colliders, and instead of "ontrigger", check "oncollisionenter2d": https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, using `Triggers` to check this type of collision is probably not the best way forward. I would suggested **not** using triggers, and instead using `OnCollisionEnter2D()`. `Triggers` just detect if the collision space of two objects has overlapped each other, whereas normal collisions collide against each otehr as if they were two solid objects. Seen as though you are detecting to see if you have landed on the floor, you don't want to fall through the floor like `Triggers` behave.

Second, I would suggest using `AddForce` instead of `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity`.

Your final script could look like something like this:

```c#
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{         
     public float jumpForce = 10.0f;     
     public bool isGrounded;
     Rigidbody2D rb;

     void Start()
     {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     }

     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
     {
         // If we have collided with the platform
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "YourPlatformTag")
         {
             // Then we must be on the ground
             isGrounded = true;
         }
     }

     void Update()
     {
         // If we press space and we are on the ground
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
         {     
             // Add some force to our Rigidbody
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

             // We have jumped, we are no longer on the ground
             isGrounded = false;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: By "YourPlatformTag" you mean the mother of all my platforms? or do you mean each children's name? I am sorry, I am new to this. And thanks for the tips I did not even ask (not being sarcastic), all tips help :)

Comment: With each of your platforms, if you look in the inspector, in the top right there is a tag option. Here you can create your own tags and apply it to all your platforms :-) So you could create one called "Platform" and change "YourPlatformTag" to "Platform"

Comment: your code worked like a charm thanks a lot :) but i still would like to figure out why the trigger jumping would not work on only specific parts of the same platform, i might have to use it in the future? (i dont know)

Comment: Perhaps your character is colliding with more than just a platform, or multiple platforms at once? In your post, you do not check what you collide with, it basically says `whatever we collide with, set grounded to false`. Maybe it got confused between 2 states of being `grounded = true` and `grounded = false`?

Comment: I see thanks man, I would hate to take advantage of your help, but do you know why my character gets stuck on the sides? I can understand why but I don't know how to fix it.. https://imgur.com/a/J0iF9

Comment: @EricAhn Looks to me that you have 2 colliders on your walls and your character is getting stuck on them. I suggest having one collider for your wall or having a collider on your characters feet that isn't square, perhaps a circle.

Comment: after your code I did not require 2 colliders for the same platform so I removed one. So I have 1 collider for the character and 1 for the platform

Answer (score 3):

It happens because your squares have seperate colliders. Imagine this:

There are two blocks : `A` and `B`. You are standing on block `A`. Now you try to walk on block `B`. As soon as your `Rigidbody2D` collider touches block `B`, your character gets an event `OnTriggerEnter2D(...)`. Now you claim, that you are grounded.
However, at this moment you are still colliding with block `A`. As soon as your `Rigidbody2D` no longer collides with block `A`, your character receives `OnTriggerExit2D(...)`. Now you claim, that you are no longer grounded. But in fact, you are still colliding with block `B`.

### Solution

Instead of having `bool` variable for checking if grounded, you could have `byte` type variable, called `collisionsCounter`:

- Once you enter a trigger - increase the counter.
- Once you exit a trigger - decrease the counter.

**Do some checking to make sure you are actually above the collider!**

Now, once you need to check if your character is grounded, you can just use

```
if (collisionsCounter > 0)
{
    // I am grounded, allow me to jump
}
```

### EDIT

Actually, after investingating question further, I've realized that you have totally unnecessary colliders (I'm talking about the trigger ones). Remove those. Now you have only one collider per object. But to get the calls for collision, you need to change:

- `OnTriggerEnter2D(...)` to `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)`
- `OnTriggerExit2D(...)` to `OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D)`

### Final code

```cs
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public sealed class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A constant with tag name to prevent typos in code
    private const string TagName_Platform = "Platform";



    public float Speed;
    public float Jump;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private byte platformCollisions;



    // Check if the player can jump
    private bool CanJump
    {
        get { return platformCollisions > 0; }
    }



    // Called once the script is started
    private void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        platformCollisions = 0;
    }

    // Called every frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // // // // // // // // // // // // // //
        // Need to check for horizontal movement
        // // // // // // // // // // // // // //

        // Trying to jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyDode.UpArrow) && CanJump == true)
            Jump();
    }

    // Called once Rigidbody2D starts colliding with something
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.tag == TagName_Platform)
            platformCollisions++;
    }

    // Called once Rigidbody2D finishes colliding with something
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.tag == TagName_Platform)
            platformCollisions--;
    }



    // Makes Character jump
    private void Jump()
    {
        Vector2 velocity = myRigidbody.velocity;
        velocity.y = Jump;
        myRigidbody.velocity = velocity;
    }
}
```

Here can be minor typos as all the code was typed inside Notepad...

Comment: the reason i have two box colliders is that if i only use one, and activate the trigger, my character passes through it. I actually saw it on some tutorial and they were using two and it was just working fine, not sure why it wont work on mine. do you have any other tips on how to use only ONE box collider and make my character not fall through it?

Comment: It is perfectly fine (not so much performance-wise) that single block uses 2 colliders. What I meant is that each of your platforms has a seperate set of colliders. And when you go from one platform to another, the thing with entering and exiting happens.

Comment: @EricAhn Edited my answer for both problems (jumping and colliders count)

Comment: Svedas I am sorry I am really new at this, when I try to use OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) and OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D) I get an error on the last parenthesis " Collision details returned by 2D physics callback functions. Identifier expected."

Comment: @EricAhn The error says that you haven't given names for Collision2D arguments in methods. So OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) should be something like OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collisionVariableName). Just think of something more descriptive for the name of the variable. The same goes for OnCollisionExit2D(...).

Comment: Svedas I actually tried putting a variable which worked in the sense that I did not get any errors, but my character would not jump. Do you happen to know any good extensive tutorials focused on jumping so I dont have to bother you with these dumb questions?

Comment: No... it has been quite some some time since I've watched any Unity tutorial (not talking about best practices, tips, etc.). I will edit my answer so that you could just copy and paste the code...